# unique() seems to be adding another copy of the last element

Tags: c++, vector, unique

When I call unique() in this code, the output ends up having a copy of the final element tacked on at the end.

```
vector<vector<int>> ints;
for(int i(0); i<files; i++)
{
    stringstream stream(list[i]);
    int num(0);
    vector<int> aList;
    for(int j(0); j<list[i].length(); j++)
    {
        if(stream.peek() == ' ')
                stream.ignore();
        while (stream >> num)
        {
            aList.push_back(num);
            if(stream.peek() == ' ')
                stream.ignore();
        }
    }
    ints.push_back(aList);
    unique(ints[i].begin(), ints[i].end());
}
```

I have a vector of strings (that are actually lists of integers) called `list` that are being parsed into ints and being stored in a multidimensional vector. unique() is meant to strip the duplicates from the integer vectors that get created.

Anyway, my question is this: How can I get unique() to stop tacking on an extra element?

Comment: Its not tacking them on the end; *you're* not removing the duplicates, which `std::unique` *swaps* to the end during its algorithm. `ints[i].erase(std::unique(ints[i].begin(), ints[i].end()), ints[i].end);`. And side-note, your stream extraction is formatted, so there is no reason to slurp the surrounding whitespace.

Comment: You should take a look at how it work exactly, since you are not using it in the correct way: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique

Comment: And now that I look at it, you may find [something like this](http://pastebin.com/YKVbECLU) a little more... brief.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique), you'll note that it:

> Removes all consecutive duplicate elements from the range [first, last) and returns a past-the-end iterator for the new *logical* end of the range.

Emphasis in the original. The return is only where the end *should* be - this algorithm doesn't actually erase any elements from the container since it can't know how to do this in the general case.

That's why you need to take the result of `unique` and pass it into `erase`. From the example in the documentation:

```
auto last = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end());
v.erase(last, v.end());
```

Or for your specific case:

```
ints[i].erase(
    // new logical end 
    std::unique(ints[i].begin(), ints[i].end()),
    // actual end
    ints[i].end());
```

Also note that `unique` only removes *consecutive* duplicates - not *all* duplicates. In case you really want trully unique results, you'll need to `sort` your vector first.

Comment: thanks so much! sorry it took a while for me to get back. this solved it. the vector is given to me sorted, so i don't need to worry too much about it. thanks for making sense of the documentation for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood what `std::unique` does. It does not remove any elements from the container. It merely shifts the elements such that the unique elements are pushed to the front.

It returns an iterator that marks the logical end of the container. The physical end of the container remains unchanged.

The elements between the logical end of the container and the physical end of the container have unspecified values.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique:

> Removing is done by shifting the elements in the range in such a way that elements to be erased are overwritten. Relative order of the elements that remain is preserved and the physical size of the container is unchanged. Iterators pointing to an element between the new logical end and the physical end of the range are still dereferenceable, but the elements themselves have unspecified values. A call to unique is typically followed by a call to a container's erase method, which erases the unspecified values and reduces the physical size of the container to match its new logical size.